# How to use VBscript to convert 2 folder path content into text file. It must also only extract out "outlook Item" file type only

Tags: vba

I have created my visual basic script which will extract out all the files from folder C: and convert it to text file. This only works for 1 folder path and i unable to create for two path . My text file also contains all the files with file sizes from folder C: but i only need "Outlook Item" from the folder C: to be extracted out into text. Please have a look to my script below;

```
Sub Tester()

Dim ObjOutFile

    Set ObjOutFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). _
                     CreateTextFile("D:\Users\User\Desktop\outcome.txt")

    ListFiles ObjOutFile, "D:\MOV1", "Outlook Item"
    ListFiles ObjOutFile, "D:\MOV2", "Outlook Item"

    ObjOutFile.Close

End Sub


Sub ListFiles(f, folderPath As String, fileType As String)
Dim ObjFiles, ObjFile, sz

    fileType = UCase(fileType)
    Set ObjFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
                                .getfolder(folderPath).Files

    For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
        If UCase(ObjFile.Type) = fileType Then
            sz = Round(ObjFile.Size / 1024, 2)
            f.WriteLine sz & String(50 - Len(sz), " ") & ObjFile.Path
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry... It should be, 'Creating an Output File to write the File sizes Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\outcome.txt")

Comment: Works fine for me.  You know you have a missing line break between the `ListFiles` sub header and the following `Dim` statement though?

Comment: hi Tim, I will try again. I  will let you know once i do the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim ObjOutFile

    Set ObjOutFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). _
                     CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\outcome")

    ListFiles ObjOutFile, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder A", "Outlook Item"
    ListFiles ObjOutFile, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder B", "Outlook Item"

    ObjOutFile.Close

End Sub


Sub ListFiles(f, folderPath As String, fileType As String)
Dim ObjFiles, ObjFile, sz

    fileType = UCase(fileType)
    Set ObjFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
                                .getfolder(folderPath).Files

    For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
        If UCase(ObjFile.Type) = fileType Then
            sz = Round(ObjFile.Size / 1024, 2)
            f.WriteLine sz & String(50 - Len(sz), " ") & ObjFile.Path
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, your script works well but i still need to keep the file size which converts to KB, e.g, For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles 
    size = Round(ObjFile.size / 1024, 2) 
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine size & String(50 - Len(size), " ") & ObjFile.Path 
Next. Any idea how i can enter your script to generate into text file with the file size and file type "Outlook Item"? Another Question is, how about 2 different folder path and convert into text file? Your answer is much appreciated!

Comment: You asked about how to only process outlook items - my answer only addressed that.  If there are other problem you're having then you need to ask more specific questions

Comment: My apology for that. I tried but i could not find the answer.

Comment: Tim, i have another question... can i change the file type, e.g. Outlook Item to other file types? Will it work for other file type or i need to create a new script?

Comment: I cannot get any results. Please refer to the edited script above. When i execute, it shows Line:16
Char:29
Error:Expected')'

Comment: @KuganRaj You're running the code as VBScript, not as VBA. There are some [relevant differences](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info) between the two languages.

Comment: I was going by the "VBA" tag (since removed)